# Haystack 'anti-censorship' software alternatives?

Tags: security

The most recently lauded example, [Haystack](http://www.haystacknetwork.com/), has been [widely criticised](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2010/sep/17/haystack-software-security-concerns) of late.

Are there any better regarded alternatives?

Comment: Also, is it just me, or does anyone else picture a little *ping* sounding somewhere in GCHQ / Langley when a question like this is asked?

Comment: Just read the article now. Too bad it didn't work out the way it should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tor](http://www.torproject.org/) will do it, though I'm unsure about countries with oppressive internet filtering.